# Finding focused item in iframe

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

I'm trying to find the focused item within an iframe but failing!

Whenever I insert into the iframe the item appears to be focused, for example if I insert a table then the cursor is always in the last cell.

As a I test I am trying to change the background color of the cell to see if it is working but this always changes the iframe body not the item inserted

```
var d1 = $.Deferred();

$.when(d1).then(function () {                
    var $iframe = $("#ifr").contents();
    var focused = $iframe.find(':focus');
    focused.css("background", "red");
    console.log(focused);
})

d1.resolve(insertTable(html));
```

`d1` is just a call of a function that uses the execCommand() to insert into the iframe.

Is it at all possible to find the focused element and store it in this method?

Comment: Because there is no element which is focused (except Iframe itself) when an iframe loads. Firs t you need to make some elements to be focus then only you can get those elements.

Comment: When the table is inserted the cursor is active inside one of the cells, so something must be focused or active?  also the table resize handlers are active

Comment: Can you please add a fiddle example so to have a look onto the issue you are facing

Comment: Maybe you could try to solve this using `Window.postMessage()`. With this you can send events from iframe to parent. So you can talk to the parent from the iframe when something gets focused inside the iframe. See the documentation here: [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)

Answer (score 2):

[The `body` element is the fallback if no other element has focus](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#focus):

> There may be no element focused; when no element is focused, key events received by the document must be targeted at the body element, if there is one, [...] User agents [...] may support **only one focused element per top-level browsing context** — user agents should follow platform conventions in this regard.

See also [the CSS `:focus` selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus). Your problem is that only one element in the whole *browsing context* can have focus. If the focus is not within the `iframe`, it is somewhere else, and the `iframe`'s `body` element is that fallback.

https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#nested-browsing-context says that `iframe`s are nested browsing contexts, not top-level browsing contexts. So is seems as though there's only one focused element for the whole page. If that is not within your `iframe`, its `body` is returned instead.

Answer (score 0):

Put this script inside your iframe page.

```
$("body").delegate( "*", "focus blur", function() {
  var elem = $( this );
  setTimeout(function() {
    elem.toggleClass( "focused", elem.is( ":focus" ) );
  }, 0 );
});
```

Sample iframe page is -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
        .focused {background: #F00;}
    </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="#">
  First name:<br><input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey" >
  <br>
  Last name:<br><input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
  <br><br><input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 

<script>
$("body").delegate( "*", "focus blur", function() {
  var elem = $( this );
  setTimeout(function() {
    elem.toggleClass( "focused", elem.is( ":focus" ) );
  }, 0 );
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```